# How run external tool before run config but not suspend execution of second run config/app?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, external-tools

I have created an "External Tool" that runs a `tail` command and set it to run prior to final running of my application. But since `tail` doesn't end, it never runs my app! How can i make IntelliJ run the external tool asynchronously so it doesn't stop all the steps in the run config?